# How can I revert to a fallback in a Rails has_many dependent: :destroy scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Imagine a scenario where I have a model that has categories.
The model belongs_to a category, and the category has_many models.
The has_many relationship has a dependent: :destroy condition.

However I have a default category (essentially "not specified") that I would like to use as a fall back. So imagine category 1 is deleted - what should happen is that all the records of the model that were associated with category 1 should automatically be assigned to "not specified".

Any hints into the right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you saying is that you don't want to destroy dependent models:

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :models #,dependent: :destroy

  before_destroy do
    models.update_all(category_id: Category.first.id) # fallback to default category
  end
end
```

**Update** Let's double check.

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  before_destroy do
    posts.update_all(category_id: Category.find_by(name: "DEFAULT").id)
  end
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

```rb
Category.create(name: "DEFAULT")
Category.create(name: "ONE", posts: [Post.new, Post.new])
Category.create(name: "TWO", posts: [Post.new, Post.new])

>> Post.joins(:category).group("categories.name").count
=> {"ONE"=>2, "TWO"=>2}

>> Category.find_by(name: "TWO").destroy
>> Post.joins(:category).group("categories.name").count
=> {"ONE"=>2, "DEFAULT"=>2}   # posts from category TWO moved to DEFAULT

>> Category.find_by(name: "ONE").destroy
>> Post.joins(:category).group("categories.name").count
=> {"DEFAULT"=>4}             # posts from category ONE moved to DEFAULT
```

Comment: perfect - that will solve it :) - rubocop complained about not having a "dependent" action specified... so I guess that has to be ignored in that case.

Comment: @tkhobbes `:dependent` option creates a callback, we just have our own callback now to handle dependents. just add a comment `# rubocop:disable Rails/HasManyOrHasOneDependent`

Comment: actually - the solution is not quite right, as it updates ALL records. I obviously only want to update the records that had the category assigned that was deleted.... will check further on how to achieve this.

Comment: @tkhobbes It should only update related records. i've only done a basic example. your relationships might be different. see the update ^

Comment: Weird. I am testing this in my app. It's "books" and "book_formats" (hardcover, softcover etc), with a default format of "not specified". When I work with the test data, I have a random number of books for each book_format. When I delete any of the formats, all books are then in "not specified". I will test further.